# How to display a static image in case users have javascript switched off on there browser

Tags: css

my website has an image slider using Jquery. If a user turns off javascript what is the alternative way of just showing a static image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `noscript` tag:

```
<noscript>
    <img src="no-js.png" />
</noscript>
```

Comment: I have tried this but the replacement image does not appear where it should within the image placeholder.  Using this puts the image over the logo and through everything else out of position.

Comment: That's a CSS issue, can't do anything about it without seeing your code.

Comment: Heres the site: www.beeniebudsandco.com

Answer (score 0):

If you add:

```
<img id="fallback" src="fallback.jpg"/>
```

in the area you want the fallback image to go, you can add the following javascript:

```
document.getElementById("fallback").style.display = "none";
```

This will hide the image when javascript is enabled and the image will be displayed if javascript is not present.

Comment: Ok, so do I place the img id in the body, and with the js code can that go after the last of the four slider images?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML noscript tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 ...
</script>
<noscript>
...
</noscript>
```